# cookie doesn't get created on IE and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, cookies, cross-browser

We have an aspx page that needs a cookie in order to start. Before redirecting to that page, we create the cookie and it is given on the response then the redirect to the page.

```
Form form = new Form { 
            FormID = dalObject.FormID, 
            PageName = dalObject.PageName, 
            ViewPageName = dalObject.ViewPageName };

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("FormCookie");
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);

        if (dalObject.FormID==(int)Forms.SP_APP_FORM)
        {
            cookie.Values.Add("ApplicationRepositoryID",GetEncryptedToken(applicationRepositoryID.ToString()));
            cookie.Values.Add("UserDirectoryID", GetEncryptedToken(userDirectoryID.ToString()));
            cookie.Values.Add("FormID", GetEncryptedToken(dalObject.FormID.ToString()));

            if (applicationFormID.HasValue)
                cookie.Values.Add("ApplicationFormID", GetEncryptedToken(applicationFormID.ToString()));
        }
        form.PageCookie = cookie;
        return form;
```

The problem is that in the development environment it is working just fine, in production it is working too (for them), but if we try the production site, it does not work (from our development computers). We suspect the cookie doesn't get created. And this happens on 2 of 3 computers of the development. on one of them it is working.
We tried to delete the cookies, clear cache, but no result.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure cookies are enabled on those machines? To check in Chrome go to Settings > Advanced > Content Settings > Cookies

Comment: yes, cookies are enabled

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on our sites before. In our case the client and server clocks were significantly out of sync with one another. The server sets the expiry time, the client checks that against its own clock and if it is more than (in your case) a minute too fast then it immediately expires.

We set the expiry on the cookie to be much further away (say a week or month) and then do the checks on the server only (because it should be checking against itself). Basically, we added additional data (a manual expiry time) to the cookie that the server could use to do its checks. If it has expired by your reckoning (the one minute you set) then the server deletes (and ignores) the cookie that it was sent.

I don't know if this is the best solution to the problem, but it worked for us.

Incidentally, we only found the issue on IE.

Comment: right, but on one of our development machines, in the same lan(we have the same date time), it works, on other two it doesn't...